# CRegKey Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to build a setup bootstrapper which needs to run on every OS from XP to 8. I need a way to detect if the .NET Framework is installed.

I am currently using CRegKey, but when upgrading to Visual Studio 2012 CRegKey does not seem to exist (atlbase.h). [This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xka57xy4.aspx) says that "This class and its members cannot be used in applications that execute in the Windows Runtime."

Is there another class I can use to read from the registry, or can I detect the installed .NET version another way?

Comment: CRegKey is alive and well in VS2012.  Sounds to me that you are using the Express edition, it does not support ATL.  Using the winapi is a fallback.

Comment: Wow, @HansPassant, you're right. I am using Express. Thanks for the tip about WinAPI. I'll give it a shot.